# Unable to loop through dictionary to compare 2 strings and return max ratio in Python

Tags: python, csv, for-loop, dictionary

I have a list of items stored in csv. I am trying to compare an item name to the csv list to see if there is a match. I load the csv list to a dictionary then pass it into the function. Each item on the dictionary will be compared to the input item which will give a matching ratio. I want to return the item with the highest ratio and the highest ratio must also be higher than the set max ratio.

Example of item csv file

```
001 green apple
002 red apple
003 orange
004 mango
```

This is what I have tried so far

```
def fuzzy_token_set_matching(index_dict, str_for_comparison):
    matching_threshold = 70 

    #If I try to get dict size here, it's 0
    print(len(index_dict))     

    for index, indexed_string in index_dict.items():       
        max_ratio = 0
        #Compare input name vs name in dictionary
        fuzz_matching_ratio = fuzz.token_sort_ratio(indexed string, str_for_comparison)        
        if fuzz_matching_ratio > max_ratio:
            max_ratio = fuzz_matching_ratio            

            if max_ratio > matching_threshold:
                return index, indexed_string                
            else:
                return None

input_file = 'index.csv'
output_file = 'results.csv'

#Load index list into a dictionary
with open(input_file, mode = 'r') as index_infile:
    index_reader = csv.reader(index_infile)
    index_dict = {rows[0]:rows[2] for rows in index_reader}

print(fuzzy_token_set_matching(index_dict, 'green apple'))

>>> Current results return: 0 
>>> Correct result: 001 green apple
```

For some reason I am getting None for every results even if there is an exact match which should return 100.

Comment: Is your csv file delimited by spaces or comma? default delimiter is comma, but your csv file seems to be delimited by spaces.

Comment: What's `token_sort_ratio`? is it a method? what it returns?

Comment: @AnandSKumar - It's separated by ','

Comment: @Kasramvd - it's a method to compute two strings then return an integer between 0-100

Comment: Also, what is `return index_index, title ` , neither of them have been defined in your function.

Comment: @AnandSKumar - It should return 001 green apple.

Comment: The `for` loop in `fuzzy_token_set_matching()` isn't going to run if the length of `index_dict` is zero. But once you fix that, the `for` loop will return on the first iteration.

Comment: If your input data is separated by ',' then you should edit your question to show that explicitly. Also, the first 2 lines of your data have 3 fields but the last 2 lines only have 2 fields. That doesn't look right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue you have is that you're always returning after the first pass of the loop, even when there are more items to consider. Here's the relevant part of the code:

```
for index, indexed_string in index_dict.items():
        #...
        if max_ratio > matching_threshold:
            return index_index, title                
        else:
            return None
```

You don't want that `else` clause to be run every time, but only if the loop ends without a match that meets your threshold. Try instead:

```
for index, indexed_string in index_dict.items():
        #...
        if max_ratio > matching_threshold:
            return index_index, title
return None
```

You could also just let the function end without an explicit `return None` line, since that's the default, but I'd recommend keeping the `return` statement to make it clear that it is intentional.

Note that this will return the first match that exceeds the threshold, but not necessarily the best match. If you want the best match only, you probably want to save the max index and then move both parts of the `if` out of the loop:

```
for index, indexed_string in index_dict.items():
    #...       
    if fuzz_matching_ratio > max_ratio:
        max_ratio = fuzz_matching_ratio
        max_index = index
        max_string = indexed_string

if max_ratio > matching_threshold:
    return max_index, max_string          
else:
    return None
```

Comment: Is there a way to return all matches with this for loop?

Comment: Sure, you could build a list, or replace the `return index, indexed_string` line in the original code with a `yield` statement to turn your function into a generator (get rid of the `else` branch in that case).

Comment: Thanks! It's been 2 years since I last used python. Looks like I would need more practice...